# Is there any Interactive Testing Tool for a Command Line Application on both Windows (.bat) and Linux (.sh) System

Tags: command-line

I have a Command Line application which has both Windows (.bat) and Linux (.sh) version. Now I am looking for some testing tool to interactively test it on both OS. Mechanism of the application is similar to Oracle's SQL Plus. After the application is started, it keeps listening to user's enter and gives response accordingly.

I need a tool to work interactively with the Application by providing user enter and retrieving response and verify if the response is expected. Plus, the tool need to be applicable for both Window and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a variety of tools, all that is necessary is that the test program writes something to the Standad Input of the program under test, and checks the Output.

Examples:

**Bash**

```
echo "test input" | my_application | grep "expected output"
```

**Python**

```
completed = subprocess.run(["my_application"], capture_output = True, stdin="test input")
output = completed.stdout
# check that the output is as expected
```

Similar things are possible for basically all languages that can launch external processes.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has the wonderful `expect` and `send` pair of programs.  Typically used for things like automating dialing to a ISP via modem, where you expect a prompt and then send a reply.

Quick google shows win32 builds of the same tool available.